# Is there alternative to get middle element from array using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I tried this code and it produces me wanted result:

```
const {
  __,
  compose,
  converge,
  divide,
  identity,
  length,
  prop
} = require("ramda");

const div2 = divide(__, 2);
const lengthDiv2 = compose(Math.floor, div2, length);
const midElement = converge(prop, [lengthDiv2, identity]);

console.log(midElement([1, 5, 4]); //5
```

But I dont know is there another way to get property from array, particularly some other implementation of *midElement* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `midElement` by chaining [R.nth](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nth) and `lengthDiv2` because according to [R.chain](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) documentation (and @ScottSauyet):

> If second argument is a function, chain(f, g)(x) is equivalent to
>   f(g(x), x).

In this case `g` is `lengthDiv2`, `f` is R.nth, and `x` is the array. So, the result would be `R.nth(lengthDiv2(array), array)`, which will return the middle item.

```js
const { compose, flip, divide, length, chain, nth } = R;

const div2 = flip(divide)(2); // create the function using flip
const lengthDiv2 = compose(Math.floor, div2, length);
const midElement = chain(nth, lengthDiv2); // chain R.nth and lengthDiv2

console.log(midElement([1, 5, 4])); //5
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Came in while I was typing mine.  Note that this `chain` behavior on functions, while implemented by Ramda, is the only logical match for the [FantasyLand specs](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain).

Answer (score 1):

### Simplification

Yes, there is a somewhat easier way to write `midElement`.  This feels a bit cleaner:

```js
const div2 = divide (__, 2)
const lengthDiv2 = compose (floor, div2, length)
const midElement = chain (nth, lengthDiv2)

console.log (midElement ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]))  //=> 5
console.log (midElement ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0]))     //=> 5
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {divide, __, compose, length, chain, nth} = R
const {floor} = Math                                         </script>
```

(We choose [`nth`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#nth) over [`prop`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop) here only because it's semantically more correct.  `nth` is specific to arrays and their indices.  `prop` works only because of the coincidence that Javascript builds its arrays atop plain objects.)

[`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) is an interesting function.  You can find many more details in its [FantasyLand specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain).  But for our cases, the important point is how it works with functions.

```js
chain (f, g) //=> (x) => f (g (x)) (x)
```

And that explains how (here at least) it's a simpler alternative to `converge`.

Note that this version -- like your original -- chooses the second of the two central values when the list has an even length.  I usually find that we more naturally choose the first one.  That is, for example, `midpoint([3, 6, 9, 12])` would usually be `6`.  To alter that we could simply add a decrement operation before dividing:

```js
const midpoint = chain(nth, compose(floor, divide(__, 2), dec, length))
```

### But Why?

However, Ramda is not offering much useful here.  Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its main authors) offers help with many problems.  But it's a tool, and I would not suggest using it except when it makes your code cleaner.

And this version seems to me much easier to comprehend:

```js
const midpoint = (xs) => xs[Math.floor ((xs.length / 2))] 

console.log (midpoint ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]))  //=> 5
console.log (midpoint ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0]))     //=> 5
```

Or this version if you want the decrement behavior above:

```js
const midpoint = (xs) => xs[Math.floor (((xs.length - 1) / 2))] 

console.log (midpoint ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]))  //=> 5
console.log (midpoint ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0]))     //=> 7
```

### Another Option

But there are so many different ways to write such a function.  While I wouldn't really recommend it, since it's performance cannot compare, a recursive solution is very elegant:

```js
// choosing the first central option
const midpoint = (xs) => xs.length <= 2 ? xs[0] : midpoint (xs.slice(1, -1))
```

```js
// choosing the second central option
const midpoint = (xs) => xs.length <= 2 ? xs[xs.length - 1] : midpoint (xs.slice(1, -1))
```

These simply take one of the two central elements if there are no more than two left and otherwise recursively takes the midpoint of the array remaining after removing the first and last elements.

### What to remember

I'm a founder of Ramda, and proud of the library.  But we need to remember that it just a library.  It should make a certain style of coding easier, but it should not dictate any particular style.  Use it when it makes your code simpler, more maintainable, more consistent, or more performant.  Never use it simply because you can.